# What mean this error while booting?

Tags: boot

i am trying to install a linux based distribution (Androidx86) on my Tablet Tablet-PC (csl panter tab 10):
CPU: Intel Atom x5-Z8300
RAM: 2GB

Problem:
I get following error while booting:
„ can't read ctr while initializing i8042“

What does it mean, is there a way to fix it?

Thank you for answering

Answer (score 1):

This message can be safely ignored. For anyone coming from a Google search, the complete message is this:

```
i8042: Can't read CTR while initializing i8042
```

The message will appear when the Linux Kernel is unable to locate any PS/2 controller. Given that you are using a tablet with an Atom-based processor, it is unlikely that the system contains a PS/2 controller as everything — including the keyboard — is run through USB.

That said, you will probably want to look at using Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu, Bodhi Linux, or another light-weight distribution. Stock Ubuntu requires 4GB of RAM, which your tablet lacks.